# How to get the time reported by the computer in Javascript (disregarding timezones, DST, etc)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the time of my computer in Javascript, but it's returning the incorrect time (probably due to DST).

Here is the time on my computer:

[image: picture of time on the computer]

Here is the time that javascript returns:

```
Date()
"Sat May 11 2019 11:35:21 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

Comment: Isn't the hour shift the daylight saving time?

Comment: Try to console.log your timezone; console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset()); That should give you the hint!

Comment: Probably, but is there a way to get the actual time reported by the computer (ignoring DST or whatever might be causing inconsistencies)?

Comment: @RezaSaadati That question discusses passing a parameter into the date constructor. This is pretty different.

Comment: new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})

This could be a helpful snippet as well!

Comment: my output - `> Date()

> "Sat May 11 2019 08:56:45 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"` Seems like it works correctly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help me out. I think I may have been a bit unclear in what I was looking for. I was wondering if there's a way to get the time reported by the OS where the code is running. Disregarding the timezone or DST of course. Maybe it's not possible using frontend Javascript

Comment: @Shreyas I think it may be because my country uses EST but disregards DST

Comment: but does your clock on windows desktop say one time and `console.log()` give other? by the look of the image and your output, then this is an issue

Comment: If you're really looking for a solution from frontend, maybe you can try these babies, jstz.js, moment.js and moment-timezone.js

use these libraries together, to manipulate any date and time call.